# Is it possible to customize default tablespaces when installing Oracle Database 12c?

Tags: oracle, installation, tablespace

I'm having trouble with an `Oracle Database 12c Release 1` install for Linux. I am expecting to see a 'DATA01' tablespace and 'INDEX01' tablespace after I finish installation and database setup.

I follow the guide at this link https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr1-installation-on-oracle-linux-7. After the install I end up with the following default tablespaces: SYSTEM , SYSAUX , USERS , UNDOTBS1 , and TEMP.

Am I missing some customization steps to get the 'DATA01' and 'INDEX01' tablespaces to show up or should I not expect those additional tablespaces?

Answer (score 1):

> I am expecting to see a 'DATA01' tablespace and 'INDEX01' tablespace after I finish installation and database setup.

Why are you expecting that? Default installation installs default tablespaces. If you want to take control over it, create the database yourself, starting with [create database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01204) command.

It allows you to specify **default** (that would be your `data01`), temporary and undo tablespaces. Index (or any other) tablespace is added separately with [create tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7003.htm#SQLRF01403) command. Nowadays, it is usual to let Oracle handle that itself. Previously, people did create separate tablespaces for data and indexes to improve performance, but today that's not to be done.

Finally, this question should probably be placed on SE DBA, not here (as we're mostly developers).